# Datetime conversion in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to convert varchar to datetime.

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR, YEAR(GETDATE())) + '/'  + 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR, MONTH(GETDATE())) + '/' + 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR, DAY(GETDATE()) + 27), 120)
```

I am expecting the result

```
2012-07-02 00:00:00.000
```

But my script is throwing an error.

Please anyone help me.

Thanks
Gurej

Comment: Error messages are frequently designed to assist you by providing useful information. Even if you can't glean useful information from it, maybe those helping you might. *What does the error message say?*

Comment: it seems very likely poster is actually trying to remove time portion....

Comment: Whenever using `CONVERT(VARCHAR, ...)`, you should **specify a length** for the `VARCHAR` ! Otherwise you might end up getting unpleasant surprises..... so use `CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), .....)`

Answer (score 3):

Why are you starting with a `datetime`, munging it to `varchar` and then casting back to `datetime`?

Is your real question, "How do I remove the time portion of a datetime?"

If so, you do it like this:

```
select DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, getdate()), 0)
```

Or SQL Server 2008 onwards, simply:

```
select cast(CAST(getdate() as date) as datetime)
```

Or even, declare the underlying variable/column as `date`, and use

```
select CAST(getdate() as date)
```